Supressing Shorttitle in In-Text Citations of Two or More Works From the Same Author in the MLA-BibLaTeX Package
I am writing an essay in the MLA style covering multiple poems by the same author. Given that I clearly mention both the author and the title of the poems themselves in prose, I do not need to reference this in brackets as well, according to chapter 6.7 of the MLA manual (9th edition). Consequently, I would like to suppress the shorttitle that the biblatex-mla package automatically adds between brackets when multiple works of the same author are referenced, but only in specific instances; however, while the author field can be suppressed, in the documentation of the biblatex-mla package, I have neither found a method of suppressing a superfluous shorttitle by modifying the cite command, nor an alternative command that only references the required page numbers. While I could manually add a hyperlinked, bracketed in-text citation that only contains the page numbers, this is far from elegant and is unnecessarily time-consuming.
Therefore, I would like to know whether the biblatex-mla package is natively capable of suppressing a shorttitle in a bracketed, in-text citation, and if so, how I would do this.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Most of biblatex-mla's cite commands already don't show the title if there is only one work by a given author. So in the below we just pretend that there is just one work by the author.
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla-new]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\headtaillessparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\let\ifsingletitle\@firstoftwo
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:mla:starred:title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite*[381]{sigfridsson}

Lorem \autocite[381]{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \autocite*[381]{knuth:ct:a}

Lorem \autocite[381]{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite*[381]{knuth:ct:b}

ipsum \autocite*[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite*[381]{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \autocite*[381]{knuth:ct:b}

ipsum \headtaillessparencite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \headtaillessparencite[381]{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \headtaillessparencite[381]{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


